# How to properly deal with error on runtime.Caller(0)

Tags: go, runtime

I'm using `runtime.Caller(0)` to return the file name:

```
_, file, _, ok := runtime.Caller(0)
if !ok {
    // What should I do here?
}
```

I would like to know:

- Why this function in specific doesn't provide an error?
- What should I do if it fails? (Panic, fatal error?)
- What could be wrong to fail? Should I validate at all?

This is my first week using Go, so I might seem like stupid questions if you are already advanced, and I'm sorry for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "This is my first week using Go". So why are you even using runtime.Caller? To answer the questions: Do whatever fits your purpose. You did not tell us why you are interested in the call stack. I'd bet you are trying to do something fishy. Normally runtime.Caller might be used to gather debug information e.g. for logging/monitoring. If you cannot gather that information you have to decide what to do next: Log "???", do nothing, whatever. The question as stated cannot be answered.

Comment: I want to get the current file, isn't obvious by looking at the code? It should be, since I'm only getting file and ok.

Comment: Then what is the question? If ok is false you do not have the filename. Live with that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why this function in specific doesn't provide an error?

That is opinion based.

> What should I do if it fails? (Panic, fatal error?)

Whatever fits your needs.

> What could be wrong to fail?

Everything. E.g. a binary stripped of debug information.

> Should I validate at all?

Yes of course.